# Failed to set input claim in Azure B2c for Azure Active Directory mutli tenant

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have added Microsoft IDP to Custom Policy using this link [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant-custom?tabs=applications][1]. The user can click the Azure AD Account button and use their AD account to sign-up\sign-in. When the user signs up using AD account we'd like to validate the e-mail against our database. If the user's email is in our database, let them proceed and signup; otherwise we'd like to prevent them from signing up and display an error message. This would prevent creating a User in our Azure B2C AD. I used the following Technical Profile

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <Domain>commonaad</Domain>
  <DisplayName>Common AAD</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="Common-AAD">
      <DisplayName>Multi-Tenant AAD</DisplayName>
      <Description>Login with your Contoso account</Description>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect"/>
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
        <!-- Update the Client ID below to the Application ID -->
        <Item Key="client_id">00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000</Item>
        <Item Key="response_types">code</Item>
        <Item Key="scope">openid profile</Item>
        <Item Key="response_mode">form_post</Item>
        <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
        <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
        <Item Key="DiscoverMetadataByTokenIssuer">true</Item>
        <!-- The key below allows you to specify each of the Azure AD tenants that can be used to sign in. Update the GUIDs below for each tenant. -->
        <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://login.microsoftonline.com/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000,https://login.microsoftonline.com/11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111</Item>
        <!-- The commented key below specifies that users from any tenant can sign-in. Uncomment if you would like anyone with an Azure AD account to be able to sign in. -->
        <!-- <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://login.microsoftonline.com/</Item> -->
      </Metadata>
      <CryptographicKeys>
        <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_AADAppSecret"/>
      </CryptographicKeys>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="oid"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" PartnerClaimType="tid"/>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" PartnerClaimType="iss" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />

      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>

        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
      <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
        <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="ValidateProfile" />
      </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin"/>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

REST API Call Claim is

```
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Signup REST APIs</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="ValidateProfile">
      <DisplayName>Check loyaltyId Azure Function web hook</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://testprofile/emailvalidation</Item>
        <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
        <!-- Set AuthenticationType to Basic or ClientCertificate in production environments -->
        <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
        <!-- REMOVE the following line in production environments -->
        <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <!-- Claims sent to your REST API -->
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
      </InputClaims>
      <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

REST API SET with
        
 and technical profile  add set output claim as

**Questions**:

1. But  API request is having  empty body .Claim is not properly working. Any suggestion please?
2. Is it possible to call rest api only in signup flow? No need to call in signin flow
3. Is there any proper document for setting claim for Azure AD, Facebook and Google in Azure B2C

Comment: Do an authorisation code flow against your AAD, I do not believe an email claim is issued by AAD, so it is null. Once you see the token from AAD, then you can design the right claim mapping. Probably you’ll use unique_name which is the users userPrincipalName in AAD. To only do this call during Sign Up, add a validation technical profile (TP) that references the REST API TP in the SelfAsserted Local Account Sign Up TP. You need to use the IDPs reference documentation to see what their claim names are.

Comment: thanks.any example or tutorial ?